# Performing Sort on half Column Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I have a Entity (Table) Name Program and in Program there is a field (Column) Session. Session is a string field as is stored in following way.
2011 - Fall

I only want to sort on year part. Is this possible. I'm using sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See documentation for [`SQL and Generic Functions`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/functions.html). For `postgres` it is a [`substring`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html) function which you use to remove the first 7 character from the string. The final query might look like:

```
from sqlachemy import func
expr = func.substring(Program.session, 8)  # for postgresql
programs = (
    session.query(Program, expr.label("season"))
    .order_by(expr.desc())
    .all()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort using [`desc()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.desc) or [`asc()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.asc) methods. Since you have your string in the format of `YEAR - SEASON`, this will sort your data like so (assuming descending order):

```
2019 - Spring
2019 - Fall
2018 - Spring
2018 - Fall
2017 - Spring
2017 - Fall
2016 - Spring
2016 - Fall
2015 - Spring
2015 - Fall
2014 - Spring
2014 - Fall
...
```

---

This can be seen with the following example:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()

class Program(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'program'
    session = Column(String(250), primary_key=True)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///program.db')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()

for x in range(2000, 2020):
    session.add(Program(session="{} - Fall".format(x)))
    session.add(Program(session="{} - Spring".format(x)))

session.commit()
programs = session.query(Program).order_by(Program.session.desc()).all()

for x in programs:
    print x.session
```

---

This creates a `<Year> - Fall` and `<Year> - Spring` entry for each year between 2000 and 2019. It then runs a simple query asking for all of this data back in descending order. The first several lines are at the top of this answer.

Comment: Thanks For this detailed answer but i think i was not quite clear whit my requirements. Will it be possible to use order_by on season part of string e.g on Fall Winter

Comment: What is the database engine you use?

Comment: By database engine you mean which database i am using? I am using postgres.